# Rails nested associations create in specific order to maintain AR callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the snippet of JSON below I'm POSTing to an endpoint. It creates the model along with the nested associations in the JSON.  However, one of the nested associations has an AR callback on the model that requires the other nested association to exist.

```
{
  "appointment": {
    "appointment_users": [
      {
        "user_id": 1
      }
    ],
    "contract_levels": [
      {
        "comp_builder_id": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my REST `create` method in my Rails controller, it creates the Appointment and then proceeds to create one (1) `AppointmentUser` and then one (1) `ContractLevel`.

The problem I'm having is that in the `AppointmentUser` model there's an `after_create` callback that's being triggered.

In that `after_create` callback, it references the `Appointment` model's associated `ContractLevel` models.  However, it's in the middle of creating the `AppointmentUser` and hasn't yet created the `ContractLevel` associations due to ordering.

How should I work around this, or specify the order of associations?  This problem would not occur if the `ContractLevel` array of objects were created prior to the `AppointmentUser`.

Comment: I haven't seen this before. Have you tried reversing the ordering of the params? (I know that's probably not the *right* answer, but it may be a start...)

Comment: I solved my problem by moving the after create callback to the appointment.  However, there still must be some sane solution to this because I'm sure someone else has had this problem.  What do you mean by reversing the order of the params?

Comment: https://github.com/matisoffn/so33286810

Comment: I just meant having contract levels appear before appointment users in the params hash.

Comment: I know, I tried a few things to have it work that way but it wouldn't hit them first.  Is Rails/strong params reordering them?

Comment: It does reorder them based on the order inside `.permit()`, I believe.

Comment: No, I think in the order you put them in your `.permit()` call.

Comment: I have them in the order I want but they're being reordered.

Comment: Hmm... then, I'm way off. Sorry. :(